# How to divide a menu horizontaly between buttons , using CSS?

Tags: css, menu, alignment

I have a dropdown menu like this http://www.mrc-productivity.com/forum/cssdropdown.html coded using CSS.

Now I am having  little problem, let's say I have 4 menu items, and I want the total width of the parent div to be divided by each of the 4 menu items equally at all times even in different resolutions...

Right now I have the width manually set at 200px wide for each item but that's not a dynamic unit since it will mess up on different resolutions.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you'll have an exact number of items taking up equal widths, you should use percentages. For four items, in a parent div of any width, you would set the widths of the items to 25%.

To avoid going over 100% with borders or padding/margins, it would be a good idea to set `box-sizing: border-box;` on your divs, so that their widths are inclusive of those extra pixels.

Comment: thing is, I tried using %, but it messes up the whole menu for example when hovered the items will mess up the layout and expand only one to 25%

Comment: Well, percentages will work for what you're trying to achieve. If you're encountering more problems, you may have to adjust other parts of your code. Without seeing your code, I can't really help you though. I can give you [this quick example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTbx9/), demonstrating percentage width menu items and drop downs.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many `li`you end up with you can use this trick:

```
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1)      {width: 100%;}
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2),
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2)~ li  {width: 50%;}
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3),
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3)~ li  {width: 33.3333%;}
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4),
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4)~ li  {width: 25%;}
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(5),
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(5)~ li  {width: 20%;}
```

You get how it continues for more larger numbers...

I have stolen this from a blog I cannot remember. 
It is the smartest approach I have seen so far.

It shows me how little I know about CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, John beat me to it, but I too went percentages since you specifically said 4 elements.
Also make sure your li items are set to inline-table.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw7Ca/1/

```
div {
    margin: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f99;
}

ul {
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    height: 50px;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-table;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
```